# (jQuery plugin: backstretch) Margin on the sides

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this great jQuery plugin to have the fullscreen backgound for my website.
This plugin currently fills the entire background on the screen, I was wondering if it is possible to give it a margin.
For instance I want to have a gap in the right side of the screen for 150px (so I can see the body background) and the rest of the page will be filled with backstretch.
I have played with _adjustBG function but I can't get this working.
Any helps will be appreciated.

Comment: change line 88 to `bgWidth = rootElement.width() - 150;`

Answer (score 1):

Since the author of this plugin didn't make an option for margin, I'll tweak it for you.
Below is the modified _adjustBG() function that you may need.

Just open the file "jquery.backstretch.js" (the normal version, not the minimized) then replace the original _adjustBG() function (at the end of file) with this function.

```
function _adjustBG(fn) {
    var rightMargin = 150; //--- edit the margin value here
    try {
        bgCSS = {left: 0, top: 0}
        bgWidth = rootElement.width()-rightMargin;
        bgHeight = bgWidth / imgRatio;

        // Make adjustments based on image ratio
        // Note: Offset code provided by Peter Baker (http://ptrbkr.com/). Thanks, Peter!
        if(bgHeight >= rootElement.height()) {
            bgOffset = (bgHeight - rootElement.height()) /2;
            if(settings.centeredY) $.extend(bgCSS, {top: "-" + bgOffset + "px"});
        } else {
            bgHeight = rootElement.height();
            bgWidth = bgHeight * imgRatio-rightMargin;
            bgOffset = (bgWidth - rootElement.width()) / 2;
            if(settings.centeredX) $.extend(bgCSS, {left: "-" + bgOffset + "px"});
        }

        $("#backstretch, #backstretch img:last").width( bgWidth ).height( bgHeight )
                                                .filter("img").css(bgCSS);
    } catch(err) {
        // IE7 seems to trigger _adjustBG before the image is loaded.
        // This try/catch block is a hack to let it fail gracefully.
    }

    // Executed the passed in function, if necessary
    if (typeof fn == "function") fn();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but unfortunately this method stretches the image, if you re-size the window you will see that but again thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

By poking around w/ console, I found that if you subtract 150 from the width of the background-image, it will, by default, give you a margin on the right. You may want to adjust the height so your image scales, but, maybe something like this to run in $(document).ready():

```
var $bg = $('#backstretch');
var newImgWidth = $bg.width() - 150;
$bg.css('width', newImgWidth);
```

Comment: no that will not work! That way I will lose a bit (right side) of the image.

Comment: Unfortunetley that would not help either. This code will simply change the width of the layer but backstretch will revert it back to the correct ration. I think we need to alter _adjustBG function in order to this to work properly and with correct image ration.

Answer (score 0):

If IE6 is no issue, you can try to put the following in your stylesheet:

```
#backstretch{
    width: auto !important;
    right: 150px;
}
```

I tried this on the backstretch homepage and it worked as I would expect. As I am not totally familiar with this plugin please feel free to correct me.